# Indicate where to drop a div within a drop zone

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a drop and drop setup using html and javascript that works well. The question i have is how does the user know when to drop a div once in the drop zone so it doesn't overlap and destroy the previous dropped div? I have added a border change on the drop zone and it also affects the borders within the divs when hovered over(which doesn't disappear). But is there a way to have say a floating div that says drop div here that moves below the dropped div.
This is my javascript for the drag and drop:

```
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.ton').click(function(e){
        $clone = $('#addtitle').clone();
        $clone.attr('id', 'line-' + ($('.line').length + 1) );
        $clone.insertBefore($('.button-div'));
    });
    });
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: can you make any jsfiddle?

Comment: 2 advice ... if you use jquery why you mixed it with vanilla js and why you put document ready inside of function

Comment: To be honest it's a bit of a monster. I have a drag and copy with a swap function.